# Intersection of concentric circles of radii 1/n.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, circles

I read that the intersection of circles of radii $1/n$, when $n$ goes to infinity, it is equal to the center. For instance if the center is $0$, then this intersection is equal to $0$.

It was in my notes from Calculus and I also found it here:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_does_one_take_arbitrary_union_and_finite_intersection_when_defining_the_topology_of_a_set

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9oAK.jpg)

If the radii belongs to $\Re $, and the real line contains infinite points, I think that one can always find a radii bigger than $0$ when $n$ approximates infinity. So the intersection will be bigger than $0$, very small, but no $0$.  I understand that the limit of the intersection of circles of radii $1/n$ is $0$, but I don't understand that the intersection of infinite circles (without finding the limit) of radii $1/n$ as $n$ goes to infinity it is $0$.

Comment: you mean circles as a boundary or disks?

Comment: ok then you dont mean  the disk

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough. Yep, I mean a disk, not only the circle.

Comment: because the intersection only of boundaries might be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B(x_0, \frac{1}{n})=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|d_2(x,x_0)  \frac{1}{n}\}$ a disk with radius $1/n$

Let $x \in A= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B(x_0, \frac{1}{n})$ then $d(x,x_0)<\frac{1}{n},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Taking limits we have that $$0 \leqslant d(x,x_0) \leqslant 0 \Rightarrow d(x,x_0)=0 \Rightarrow x=x_0 \Rightarrow x \in \{x_0\}$$

Thus $A \subseteq \{x_0\}$

Also if $x \in \{x_0\}$ then $x=x_0 \Rightarrow d(x,x_0)=0< \frac{1}{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thus $x \in B(x_0, \frac{1}{n}), \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow x \in A \Rightarrow \{x_0\} \subseteq A$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a formal definition and maths aren't easy to me. I don't know if you can explain it in simple terms.

Comment: @falcon16  what is it that you do not understand?

Comment: In layman's words, if you intersect infinite disks of radii 1/n I don't think that this intersection equals 0 (or the center point of the disk), as you can always find a radii bigger than 0 and draw a circle with this radii. Inside this circle you can draw another circle with a shorter radius, an so on. So the intersection never equals the center point. I don't know if I explain myself.

Comment: we proved the the intesrction is a sigleton that contains the center...the distance $d(x,x_0)$ is alwalys non-negative.If we prove that this distance is less than $1\ n$ for every $n$ then it must be zero..

Comment: this intesection cannot be equal to a disk with positive radious ,fot instance $1/N$ because if it was, i.e $A= B(x_0,1/N)$  then we would have that $d(x,x_0)<1/n$ for all $n$ thus there would be an $m$ such that $d(x,x_0)<1/m <1/N$ proving the the intersection $A \subsetneq B(x_0,1/N)$

Comment: As I see it, this prove is valid when you take the limit of the intersection of infinite disks of radii 1/n. But what happens when you don't take the limit?. When you only intersect infinites disks without calculating the limit of this infinite intersection?

Comment: See my previous comment which proves that the intersection cannot be equal to any disk,but just a proper subset..you can see this without limits

Comment: What does $d_2 (x,x_0)\frac{1}{n}$ mean?

Comment: $d_2(x,x_0)<1/n$ means that the distance of $x$ from the center $x_0$ is less than $1/n$

Comment: you will see that function in the future when you will learn about metric spaces

Comment: what does the subindex 2 from $d_2$ mean?

Comment: $d_2$ denotes   the metric we give to $R^n$ which is called Euclideian metric..but that doesn't matter..you can prove the same for an arbitrary space enhanced with a metric and the notion of distance..If $x=(x_1...x_n)$ and $y=(y_1...y_n)$ in $R^n$ then $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}$..This is the usual metric you know.

Comment: You are welcome..glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is a point $z$ different from $x_0$ (which implies that $d(x_0,z)>0$) such that
$$z\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}B(x_0,1/n)$$
where $B(x_0,r)=\{x: d(x,x_0)<r\}$.

Then, by [Archimedes' Axiom](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesAxiom.html), there exists a positive integer such that $N>1/d(x_0,z)$. Hence $z\in B(x_0,1/N)$
which implies that $d(x_0,z)<1/N$ contradicting $N>1/d(x_0,z)$.

Comment: "Hence $z\in B(x_0,1/N)$". Is this true because of $z\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}B(x_0,1/n)$ or because of $N>1/d(x_0,z)$?

Comment: @falcon16 The first one!

Comment: Why does a positive integer exists such that $N>1/d(x_0,z)$?  $N$ is one of the natural numbers, I guess. Can you explain it with more detail what you are doing here? I don't understand the $d(x_0,z)$ in the denominator. If I write it like this $d(x_0,z)>1/N$, then it's easier to understand. But according to the expression $z\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}^+}B(x_0,1/n)$ that can't be possible.$d(x_0,z)$ should be smaller than $1/N$.

Comment: This is Archimedes' Axiom. Given a positive real $a$ there is an integer $N$ such that $N>a$.